# how to Monitor the current queue size in a specific node in ns-3 ？

Tags: networking, ns-3

here is my code :

```
TrafficControlHelper tchRed10;
  tchRed10.SetRootQueueDisc ("ns3::DropTailQueue", "MaxPackets",UintegerValue(10));
  QueueDiscContainer queueDiscs1 = tchRed10.Install (d0d2);
  Simulator::Schedule (Seconds (1.0), &MonitorQueueSize, queueDiscs1.Get (0));
```

```
void
MonitorQueueSize (Ptr<QueueDisc> queue)
{
  uint32_t qSize = queue->GetNPackets ();
  std::cout << "Queue size: " << qSize << std::endl;
  Simulator::Schedule (Seconds (1.0), &MonitorQueueSize, queue); 
}
```

but didn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmwUq.png)